# Keep JQuery Vars for another function (Global vars?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, passwords

I'm trying to make a password check system.
I've decided I also want to check if it is a commonly used password.

For this, I'm loading an external txt file into an array. However, my password check function does not seem to be able to read this array.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var commonPass = new Array;
jQuery.get('/static/commonPass.txt', function(data){
    commonPass = data.split('\n');
    console.log(commonPass);
});
console.log(commonPass);
//you have to use keyup, because keydown will not catch the currently entered value
jQuery('input[type=password]').keyup(function() { 

    // set password variable
    var pswd = jQuery(this).val();

    //check if common password
    console.log(pswd);
    if ( jQuery.inArray(str.toLowerCase(pswd), commonPass)!= -1) {
        console.log('InArray');
        jQuery('#known').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    } else {
        console.log('NotInArray');
        jQuery('#known').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    }

});
```

Is it possible to make global jQuery/Javascript variables and would that be the solution to this issue?

Comment: What error are you receiving when you try to comprehend the array?

Comment: The array is simply empty

Comment: KJ Prince already answerd. It is working. And it was loading perfectly fine, just couldt figure out how to access the var outside the scope of the loading function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `commonPass` outside of the scope of all functions

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var commonPass = new Array;
```

...Should be...

```
var commonPass = new Array;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

Or else you can use `window.commonPass`. `window` is javascript's "global" variable when working in the browser. Javascript's variables live inside the scope of the functions they were declared in (or `window` if outside of a function).